# localStorage doesn't work in TouchableOpacity tag

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to use localStorage and move to another page at the same time, but only moving work, I can't get the value

```
    const pressHandlerMapTest = () => {
        navigation.navigate("TestMapScreen");
      };
    return (
        <ImageBackground style={styles.background}>
            <View style={styles.tourWindow}>
                <TouchableOpacity underlayColor="red" 
                onPress={pressHandlerMapTest}
                onPressIn={() => {
                    localStorage.setItem('tour', 'others');
                  }}>
                    <Image source={require("../assets/royals.png")} ></Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                
                
            </View>
        
        </ImageBackground>

    );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    const pressHandlerMapTest = () => {
        localStorage.setItem('tour', 'others');
        navigation.navigate("TestMapScreen");
      };
    return (
        <ImageBackground style={styles.background}>
            <View style={styles.tourWindow}>
                <TouchableOpacity underlayColor="red" 
                onPress={pressHandlerMapTest}
                >
                    <Image source={require("../assets/royals.png")} ></Image>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                
                
            </View>
        
        </ImageBackground>

    );
```

Comment: It still doesn't work

Comment: const pressHandlerMapTest = () => {
        localStorage.setItem('tour', 'others').then((res) => { navigation.navigate("TestMapScreen") });
      };